# Как правильно писать cashback?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, английский-язык, транслитерация

Все пишут по-разному, встречается:

- "кэшбэк";
- "кешбэк";
- и даже "кэшбек".

Я понимаю, что в русском языке искомо такого слова может не быть, но если уж очень хочется написать такое, например в письме пользователю или на рекламной странице, то как правильно или как правильнее?

Помогите разобраться, [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA) не особо помогла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно: *кешбэк*

Именно такое написание зафиксировано в орфографическом словаре "Академос" (см. [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA&all=x)).

"Грамота.ру" также одобряет такое написание (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20302313)).

**Вопрос № 302313**

> Здравствуйте, как правильно пишется: кешбэк, кэшбэк или кешбэк? В вопросе № 277210 "Грамота" какое-то время назад давала ответ, что правильно кешбэк, но может быть уже что-то изменилось. Слово очень часто используется и, возможно, язык его уже освоил. Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> *Кешбэк* - употребительный и корректный вариант написания.